# Reading a value from a specific userid child node in database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this has been asked 100 times already but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

Want to read the database of "user_preferences" for the user that is signed in (userID) and read the gender/age/weight/height values and store them in the variables shown below. currently returns null on everything (the log statement and the values). Feel like i havent got the path set up properly or something. help would be great!

[image: db]

and my code

```
       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference testRef = myRef.child("user_preferences");


        testRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //loop through the firebase nodes

                            UserPreferences userPreferences = new UserPreferences();


                            userPreferences.setAge(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getAge()); 
                            userPreferences.setHeight(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getHeight()); 
                            userPreferences.setWeight(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getWeight()); 
                            userPreferences.setGender(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getGender());

                            genderSet = userPreferences.getGender();
                            age = userPreferences.getAge();
                            height = userPreferences.getHeight();
                            weight = userPreferences.getWeight();

                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + genderSet);
//
                        }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + genderSet);`... What does this print? Where is the code that shows the other null values?

Comment: Also, you should be querying `myRef.child("user_preferences/" + userID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the null values, you seem to be using external fields, which will not be set until the Firebase returns the network call after at least a second. Your values will be null in the meantime, so you should not be setting them onto a UI element outside of `onDataChange`.

Also, you have a lot of gets/sets going on, when you only need to call one `getValue()` for the class, then additional ones for the fields.

Then, you don't seem to want to loop over anything, so you should directly access the user node from the top reference.

For example,

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference testRef = myRef.child("user_preferences/"+userID);
    // or .child("user_preferences").child(userID)


    testRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserPreferences userPreferences = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserPreferences.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + userPreferences.getGender());

            // TODO: Update some UI element here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // TODO: Add error handling
        }
    });

}
```

If you only want to read the values once, use `testRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`

Answer (score 2):

These two lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference testRef = myRef.child("user_preferences");
testRef.addValueEventListener(...)
```

are effectively querying the **entire** node called `user_preferences`.  That means everything at that location - all users.  It sounds like this is not what you want.  If you want to query just a single user, you should be specific about that in your query by adding the userID that you want to the query location:

```
DatabaseReference testRef = myRef.child("user_preferences").child(userID);
testRef.addValueEventListener(...)
```

Also, these lines of code are confusing to me:

```
userPreferences.setAge(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getAge()); 
userPreferences.setHeight(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getHeight()); 
userPreferences.setWeight(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getWeight()); 
userPreferences.setGender(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserPreferences.class).getGender());
```

You're deserializing a UserPreferences object for each and every field you want to populate, which is wasteful.  It seems to me that you really just want to deserialize it once and remember the object:

```
UserPreferences userPreferences = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserPreferences.class);
```